# phpinfo showing HTTP_ALLOWCOOKIES set to NO - how to change?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, session, cookies, phpinfo

We have a dev and live server that were seemingly built identically. However the live server `phpinfo()` page shows the following in the "Apache Environment" section

```
HTTP_ALLOWCOOKIES NO
```

Don't see this line in the Dev environment.

Live environment session variables are not working and I'm guessing lack of apache cookie support is probably reason - but I cannot figure out how or why `HTTP_ALLOWCOOKIES` is set to NO on the live server or how to enable it. Have grep-ed PHP & Apache config files and googled a lot with no joy - I thought this would be an easy fix!

Any help/pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out nothing to do with the Apache server ("Apache Environment" is what threw me here) - there is no setting for HTTP_ALLOWCOOKIES - it's just a header being sent into the web server. Turned out it was being set by the Varnish server in front of the web servers - doh!

If anyone else comes across this - check your upstream servers - such as reverse proxy load balancers and/or caching servers :)